# Get parts of an array from percentage

Tags: arrays, ruby

I really can't wrap my head around it.
So what I want to do is get get 4 groups from an array as follow :

- result[0] <- First 10%
- result[1] <- Following 20%
- result[2] <- Following 30%
- result[3] <- Following 40%

Here's my code :

```
a = Array 0..199
puts "Array is #{a.length} entries long"
#=> 200

def percent_elements(array, from, to)
    from = (array.length * from / 100.0).ceil
    to = (array.length * to / 100.0).ceil
    a = array[from..to]
end

results = [
    percent_elements(a, 0, 10),      # First 10%
    percent_elements(a, 10, 30),     # Following 20%
    percent_elements(a, 30, 60),     # Following 30%
    percent_elements(a, 60, 100)     # Following 40%
]

puts "Result is #{results.flatten.count} entries long"
#=> 203

puts "First 10% is #{results[0].count} entries long"
#=> 21

puts "Following 20% is #{results[1].count} entries long"
#=> 41

puts "Following 30% is #{results[2].count} entries long"
#=> 61

puts "Following 40% is #{results[3].count} entries long"
#=> 80
```

Is there a better way (and functioning) to do this ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do that as follows.

**Code**

```
def partition_array(arr, cum_breaks)
  n = arr.size
  cum_breaks.map { |f| (n*f).to_i }.each_cons(2).map do|f,l|
    if f.zero?
      if l.zero?
        []
      else
        arr[0..l-1]
      end
    else
      arr[f..l-1]
    end
  end
end
```

**Examples**

```
cum_breaks = [0.0, 0.1, 0.3, 0.6, 1.0]

n = 30
arr = Array.new(n) { |i| i }
  #=> [0, 1, 2, 3,..., 28, 31] 
a = partition_array(arr, cum_breaks)
  #=> [[ 0,  1,  2],
  #    [ 3,  4,  5,  6,  7,  8],
  #    [ 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17],
  #    [18, 19, 20, 21, 22, 23, 24, 25, 26, 27, 28, 29]] 
a.map { |e| [e.size, (e.size/arr.size.to_f).round(3)] }
  #=> [[3, 0.1], [6, 0.2], [9, 0.3], [12, 0.4]]

n = 37
arr = Array.new(n) { |i| i }
  #=> [0, 1, 2, 3,..., 35, 36] 
a = partition_array(arr, cum_breaks)
  #=> [[ 0,  1,  2],
  #    [ 3,  4,  5,  6,  7,  8,  9, 10],
  #    [11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20, 21],
  #    [22, 23, 24, 25, 26, 27, 28, 29, 30, 31, 32, 33, 34, 35, 36]] 
a.map { |e| [e.size, (e.size/arr.size.to_f).round(3)] }
  #=> [[3, 0.081], [8, 0.216], [11, 0.297], [15, 0.405]]

n = 9
arr = Array.new(n) { |i| i }
  #=> [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8] 
a = partition_array(arr, cum_breaks)
  #=> [[], [0, 1], [2, 3, 4], [5, 6, 7, 8]]
a.map { |e| [e.size, (e.size/arr.size.to_f).round(3)] }
  #=> [[0, 0.0], [2, 0.222], [3, 0.333], [4, 0.444]]
```

Comment: Erwan, thanks for fixing my error. (Readers: I had `if f.zero?; arr[0..l-1]; else ; arr[f..l-1]...`, which was a problem when `n < 10`, as `l = n*cum_breaks[1].to_i #=> 0`, so `arr[0..l-1] #=> arr[0..-1] => arr`.)

Answer (score 0):

I used a different technique, a little simpler to read and understand for a Ruby beginner like me.

```
a = Array 0..199
original_length = a.length

def percents_elements(array, array_length, percent)
  p_length = (array_length * percent / 100.0).round
  a = array.slice!(0, p_length)
end

results = [
  percents_elements(a, original_length, 10),
  percents_elements(a, original_length, 20),
  percents_elements(a, original_length, 30),
  percents_elements(a, original_length, 40)
]
puts "Result is #{results.flatten.count} entries long"
print results
```